# passing instance to Django modal form

Tags: django

I want to do edit on a modal pop up form, edit is working but cant see the existing instance, how I can do it? any help is appreciated.
Here I have passed the form as below

```
class DomainListView(ListView):
    model = Domain
    template_name = 'super_admin/domain_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = DomainEditForm(self.request.POST or None)
        context['form'] = form
        return context
```

and the template is as follows

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="domain-edit-{{ item.pk }}">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <form class="form-valide" action="{% url 'domain_edit' item.pk %}" method="POST" id=""
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title"> Edit Domain </h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="basic-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         {% csrf_token %}
                          {{ form.errors }}
                          {{ form | crispy }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this is inside for loop along with list items, I tried to fetch the instance as follows in get context data override, but it gives key error

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    obj = get_object_or_404(Domain, kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
    form = DomainEditForm(self.request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    context['form'] = form
    return context
```

Comment: This is what *FormSet*s are for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: i have added like this         domain_formset = formset_factory(DomainEditForm)
        formset = domain_formset(self.request.POST or None),  here how I can pass the instance?

Comment: but there is *no* instance, at the Django level you have a queryset, so you will have to construct an indivudla form *per* object, a `FormSet` is made to generate a set of forms for each instance...

Comment: at first there is no instance, but second time inwards there is, I wanted to see it while form pop ups, now it comes as blank, is there anyway I can show it?

Comment: no, since then `get_context_data` has already been performed, `get_context_data` only execute *once* per request, and when you render the template, you already have run `get_context_data`.

Comment: yes now I understand it, thank you so much